# How to adjusts the result pointer of a simpleXML object?

Tags: php, simplexml

After looping through an entire XML object using foreach loop:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $xml) {
    echo $xml->title...
}
```

I  need to loop through it again starting from the top.

Having no better way, currently I `unset` the object and get the XML object again.

I am looking for the right way to do it, perhaps similar to using `$result->data_seek(0)` for mysqli query results or `reset($array)` for an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that is stopping you being able to loop over the data again is the way you are using

```
foreach($xml->children() as $xml) {
```

you are overwriting the original document by using `as $xml`.  So if you change the name of that field (using `$child` in this example) you can just loop over it again...

```
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->asXML().PHP_EOL;
}
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->asXML().PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.